# How to separate digits in numeric constants (i.e. 10,000) in C or C++ code

Tags: c++, c, literals

Java allows the digits in a numeric constant to be separated as follows:

```
int a = 1_000_000;
```

Does C or C++ have a similar construct?

Comment: @Rakete1111, is this C++? in C I receive an error: `expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before '\x303030'`

Comment: C is not C++ and vice versa, pick one because the answer will most likely differ.

Comment: It's C++14, not C for sure.

Comment: @AlterMann It is C++14. Yeah, didn't see the C tag :0

Comment: Thank you @Rakete1111, and whats the benefit of separate the number?

Comment: This is going to confuse the poor IDEs with syntax highlighting...

Comment: @AlterMann Well, what's more readable: `unsigned long a = 12387461;` or `unsigned long a = 12'387'461;`? :)

Comment: @AlterMann Well, it can improve readability a bit. But as I said, if it will mess the syntax highlighting, it will just make it worse..

Comment: @Rakete1111, got it, thanks ;)

Comment: Thak you @EugeneSh.

Comment: C programmers would write `0x000F4240`. Engineers would write `(int)1e6`.

Comment: @Lundin Sometimes I wish I could write `0x00_0F_42_40`

Comment: Come to think of it, C programmers probably write it as `#define x(x, y, z) x ## y ## z` then `printf("%d", x(1,000,000));`...there's no problems that can't be fixed with icky macros (the duct tape of C programming).

Comment: @EugeneSh. `#define hex32(b3, b2, b1, b0) 0x ## b3 ## b2 ## b1 ## b0` then `hex32(00,0F,42,40)`  :)

Comment: @Lundin Your `x4(10,000,000,000)` has an advantage over another way of breaking up wide constants.   `10*1000*1000*1000` can overflow.  IMO your alternate macro is worthy of an answer, but likely to attract to many nay-sayers.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, but my coworkers won't accept it gracefully, I think...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Then consider replacing your co-workers with icky macros!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27767781/995714

Comment: an alternative in C is `1000*1000*1000LL` http://stackoverflow.com/q/8488989/995714

Comment: [Making large constants in C source more readable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10977260/995714), [Representing big numbers in source code for readability?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220217/995714)

Comment: @Lundin I'm surprised you don't have an account on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) with suggestions like these...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The only way to do this is in C++14, is with single quotes, like this. Unfortunately, the only problem with this is that syntax highlighting often gets messed up with the notation below, and you can see that in my example as well:

```
int i = 1'000'000;
```

---

[Working Example](http://cpp.sh/33iuw)

---

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal:

> In the integer and floating-point digit sequences, optional separators ' are allowed between any two digits and are ignored (since C++14)

Answer (score 19):

You may write in C++ 14

```
int a = 1'000'000;
```

In C such a feature is absent.

Comment: Maybe mention that OP has to use C++14?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I do not remember is it valid in C++ 11?:)

Comment: I think [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3781.pdf) is the proposal which was accepted, but I'm not sure. It's not valid C++11.