# Making hexadecimal numbers more readable

Tags: c, literals, readability

I'm using large hexadecimal numbers in my programs and often waste time figuring out how many places the number is.

I know for base-10 numbers an easy way to grasp the size of the number is the multiply-by-1000 method:

```
// 15mhz clock
uint64_t clk_spd = 15 * 1000 * 1000;
```

But is there an easy separation method for hexadecimals? My question is effectively, instead of this:

```
// control register address
uint64_t reg_ctl_addr = 0x2400000000
```

Can I do something like this:

```
// control register address
uint64_t reg_ctl_addr = 0x24_0000_0000
```

I've tried underscores, commas, spaces, even `/**/` between the groups of 0s, and nothing compiled.

---

Edit: I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10977374/1085937) which is about decimal numbers, but it didn't compile for me:

```
 % gcc numbers.c                                                                
numbers.c:6:16: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
long m = 24##0000UL;
           ^
           ;
1 error generated.
```

Comment: If you don't need to use a "standard" environment, you might use [some custom preprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545875/custom-gcc-preprocessor) before passing the program to the compiler. You might for example use `sed` to remove all "°" characters from the program and write the number as `0x24°0000°0000` or you may write a decimal number as `24°000°000`.

Comment: Do not change your question after comments/answers have been given, as this might render the latter ununderstandable. I rolled back your last change though ...

Comment: Well, C++ (not C) since the C++14 standard allows to write `24'000'000` too.

Answer (score 3):

We can extend the multiply-by-1000 rule to base 16.

A "major jump", for lack of a better term, in base-10 is 1000. GHz = 1000*MHz, etc. In base-16, a major jump is 4 digit places over (not 4 left-shifts). `0x1` -> `0x10000`.

So, since we want 4 place shifts, and 1 place shift is a multiply by 16, we just need to multiply by 16^4

Our code becomes:

```
// control register address
uint64_t ctl_reg_addr = 0x24ull * 0x10000 * 0x10000;
```

---

Important to note here from @chux: we need to write `0x24ull` because of [this caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/1085937) of how C typing works. Basically if we just used `0x24` it would be treated as a standard `int` and the resulting multiplication would overflow

Comment: `int` overflow `0x24 * 0x10000 * 0x10000`.  Use `0x24ull * 0x10000 * 0x10000`  See  [Why write 1,000,000,000 as 1000*1000*1000 in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40633059/2410359)

Comment: Alternatively, shifts could also be useful. e.g. `0x24ull << 32`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> long m = 24##0000UL;
> ```
>
> *[...] but it didn't compile for me*

`##` is not C but used by the preprocessor only.

So you *could* do:

```
#define MY_LARGE_HEX_NUMBER 0x24 ## 0000 ## 0000 ## ULL

...

uint64_t ctl_reg_addr = MY_LARGE_HEX_NUMBER;
```

which after preprocessing but before compilation would become:

```
uint64_t ctl_reg_addr = 0x2400000000ULL
```

Comment: Ah whoops, I see now. It's been a long day :)

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is this method:

- When you type the number out the first time, type `0x24 00 00 00 00`.
- Place that part in a comment. `\\ 0x24 00 00 00 00`
- Copy/paste the number and write the declaration:
    `uint64_t reg_ctl_addr = 0x24 00 00 00 00; \\ 0x24 00 00 00 00`
- Remove spaces:
    `uint64_t reg_ctl_addr = 0x2400000000; \\ 0x24 00 00 00 00`

I also strongly recommend to add `u` suffix to all hex constants and `ll` suffix to 64 bit constants. That is: `ull`.

---

An alternative method for writing this as an integer constant expressions in a readable way is obviously bit shifts:

```
uint64_t reg_ctl_addr = 0x24ull << 32;
```